# The best way to avoid data charges by unchecking auto-update in play store

Tags: android

I have an app on the Google Play Store which is used by carers in the care industry to delivery homecare. At the moment it is being used by 1400 carers.

Some companies we give our software to may have 300 carers employed. These companies have a phone contract with a provider and have a data plan. Some data plans may only be 100MB per month.

This has caused problems, my app doesn't use much data, no where near 100MB per month. Our customers have had excessive charges on their carers phones due the phone updating other apps.

I've advised the companies to make sure that auto-update is checked, so that our app will update as and when. I have asked them to go into the play store app and uncheck auto-update in all the apps other than our app. This will stop the excessive charges.

Have i given the correct advise to stop the excessive charges or is there anything else i have missed?

Thanks in advance

Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your advice is good, there is not a lot else they can do, other than maybe turn off automatic account syncrhonisation and just do a sync when needed, although can be inconvient depending on the user.

The fact that your users are getting excessive charges isn't really your responsibility though unless your app is doing some excessive stuff with the network but you mentioned your app doesn't use too much.

If its just other apps on the device that is causing the charges then it is technically their responsibility and not you as the developer.

Comment: This is what one company has done i think. They have turned off background data. Will this stop my app updating?

Comment: I'm not too sure to be honest, I guess it probably would as it is a background process.

Comment: ok thanks alot, i'll get a document drawn up for them to follow